# How can I show that an ODE has other solutions than the trivial ones when it is not analytically solvable?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have the following first-order differential equation:
$$
(a x - b y) y'(x) - c y =0,
$$
where $a,b,c>0$ and $x>=0$.
There are two obvious solutions: $y(x)\equiv 0$ and $y(x)=\frac{a-c}{b} x$. The numerical analysis suggests that there are infinitely many solutions between these two solutions. For example, the following is a streamline plot for $a=3/4,b=7/4,c=1/4$ generated by Mathematica. The red line is the linear solution, and the yellow line is the zero function solution.

My question is, how can I rigorously show that there are infinitely many solutions between these two trivial solutions? Or, at the very least, can I formally show that there is one solution that is one of the above solutions? Since an explicit construction seems not feasible, I don't know where to start.

[image]

```
a = 3/4; b = 7/4; c = 1/4;
gr1 = StreamPlot[{1, (c y)/(a x - b y)}, {x, 0, 2}, {y, -.05, 1}];
gr2 = ContourPlot[y == (a - c)/b x, {x, 0, 2}, {y, 0, 3}, ContourStyle -> Red];
sol3 = DSolve[{(a x - b y[x]) y'[x] - c y[x] == 0, y[0] == 0}, y, {x, 0, 2}][[1]];
gr3 = Plot[Evaluate[y[x] /. sol3], {x, 0, 2}, PlotStyle -> Yellow];
sol4 = NDSolve[{(a x - b y[x]) y'[x] - c y[x] == 0, y[1] == .2}, y, {x, 0, 2}][[1]];
gr4 = Plot[Evaluate[y[x] /. sol4], {x, 0, 2}, PlotStyle -> Green];
Show[gr1, gr2, gr3, gr4]
```

Comment: The Picard–Lindelöf theorem with varying initial conditions might be helpful.

Comment: To my understanding, the [theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picard%E2%80%93Lindel%C3%B6f_theorem) gives a sufficient condition for the uniqueness, so it is not clear how to use the theorem to show that the solution is not unique. I already have two solutions so the theorem doesn't apply, but it does not mean there are other solutions, right?

Comment: @keepfrog for any choice of initial condition, our hope is that the ODE will have a unique solution that satisfies the initial condition. Since there are infinitely many initial conditions to choose from, there are infinitely many solutions.

Comment: @AlannRosas But even if we fix $y(0)=0$, we get infinitely many conditions, no? The streamline suggests that even for $y(x)=c_0$ for some $x>0$, there are multiple solutions.

Comment: @keepfrog you are correct, but if the goal is merely to prove that there are infinitely many solutions between the two you identified, then we can get away with A rural reader's technique.

Comment: @AlannRosas Is this how to use the theorem?: Fix $x_0>0$. By the theorem, for any $y_0$, there is a locally unique solution satisfying $y(x_0)=y_0$. There are infinite ways of picking $y_0$, so there are infinitely many solutions. (Since the function that defines the ODE is not Lipschitz continuous at zero, there are multiple solutions for $y_0=0$.)

Comment: @keepfrog provided you've shown the function defining the ODE is Lipschitz in $y$, that's the idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In fact, we can find exact solutions for this ODE.

For $x>0$, division by $x$ shows that the equation is equivalent to

$$\left(a-b\frac{y(x)}{x}\right)y'(x)-c\frac{y(x)}{x}=0$$

or, provided we stipulate that $a-b\frac{y(x)}{x}$ never be zero,

$$y'(x)=\frac{c\frac{y(x)}{x}}{a-b\frac{y(x)}{x}}$$

Writing $F(t):=ct/(a-bt)$, it can be seen that our transformed equation is

$$y'(x)=F\left(\frac{y(x)}{x}\right)$$

which is a first-order homogeneous differential equation. We can solve such equations by introducing the substitution $v(x):=y(x)/x$ and transforming the equation into a separable one in terms of $v$:

$$y'(x)=F\left(\frac{y(x)}{x}\right)\rightarrow \frac{v'(x)}{F(v(x))-v(x)}=\frac{1}{x}$$

After integrating and substituting $u=v(x)$, we are left with evaluating $\int \frac{1}{F(u)-u} du$, which is amenable to elementary techniques since $F(u)=cu/(a-bu)$ is a rational function.

Comment: This led to $a-c-b(y/x) -(y/x)^{(2a-c)/c} + C= 0$, where $C$ is some constant. I can verify that $y(x)=0$ and $y(x)=(a-c)/b * x$ indeed satisfy this, but since this is implicitly defined, how can we say that there are other solutions that satisfy this? Also, the trick does not seem to work if we add a constant inside the first term, i.e., $(ax-by+d)y'(x)-cy=0$. Is there any way that does not rely on the solution of the ODE?

Answer (score 2):

$$(a x - b y) y'(x) - c y =0$$
$$(a x - b y)  - cx' y =0$$
$$a x   - cx' y =by$$$$
x'-\dfrac a{cy}x=-\dfrac bc$$
Should  be integrable and at least lead to an implicit solution.
$$x(y)=f(y)$$